# Mounting Sigma 70-300mm 1:4-5.6 APO Macro Super on Nikon D3200

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, macro-lenses, nikon-d3200

I have been given a Sigma 70-300mm 1:4-5.6 APO Macro Super lens and I want to fit it to my D3200. The problem is that the mount on the bottom of the Sigma lens is too big for the D3200 lens mount and I don't know what mount adapter I need. It is not the screw adapter, it is the one when you take the lens off. I think the Sigma is a 58 and the Nikon is 52...

[image: Lens 1][image: Lens 2]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the lens mount in the question?

Comment: here is a pic of lens

Comment: Sorry Vaughn, the lens is of the Canon EF type and will simply not fit since it's the wrong one.

Comment: It says Canon right on it, lol

Answer (score 9):

The Sigma 70-300 mm F4-5.6 DG APO Macro is a lens that is available for both Sigma cameras and as a third party lens for many other brands, among them Nikon. These different manufacturers uses different lens mounts and this particular lens is available for Canon EF, Nikon F (FX), Pentax KAF, Sigma SA Bayonet and Sony/Minolta Alpha mounts. These mounts are not of the same physical size and not compatible with each other.

The lens that you were given is not of the Nikon F type so it wont fit. The mount of your lens is called Canon EF. That mount is a bit bigger and looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately you can't easily use this mount without using an adapter that will both remove autofocus, aperture control and more as well as losing image quality or not being able to focus at infinity. For a lens this cheap it's simply not worth it.

Comment: here is a pic of the lens

Comment: You could just sell it and buy the Nikon version, that might be the cheapest option.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can ask for a [bayonet replacement](http://www.wantinews.com/news-5052513-Sigma-launch-paid-lens-mount-replacement-service.html). Not sure your lens can be serviced, though.

Comment: That service doesn't apply to the 75-300.

Comment: while it's not in the list on that site, that news is one year old, so I think it's worth to send an email to sigma.

Comment: @rookiecoder The service is for their "Global Vision" series: Art, Contemporay and Sports lenses. These are premium lenses and the lens in question is one of their very cheapest and of course not a part of these product lines. They won't change the mount and even if they did, the postage and replacement would cost around as much as the lens itself.

Comment: Even if the service were available, the cost would be greater than the value of the lens. Just not a sensible use of money for a cheap lens like the 75-300.